# c++ extern unresolved symbol error LNK2001

Tags: c++, extern, unresolved-external

I have something like this:

```
--includes.h
extern int count;

--main.cpp
#include "includes.h"
int count = 4;

--other.cpp
#include "includes.h"
cout<<count; // will output 4
```

but when I did this, the compiler errors out with the following message:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int count" (?count@@3HA)
```

Any idea why I am getting this?

What is the best way to share variables across different files?
How can I define use a variable in one file, and modify that same variable in another file?

Comment: Using functions and headers.

Comment: Did you link to the appropriate object file? Probably not.

Comment: *Both* .cpp files are in the same project, *right*?

Comment: yes they are in the same project

Comment: Please show how you are invoking the linker.

Answer (score 0):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int y; 
int testy();
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

     std::cout << y;
     std::cout<<testy();
     std::cout << y;
    return 0;
}
```

source.cpp

```
extern int y;

int testy(){return y++;}
```

This should help understand your issue...

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put in into unnamed namespace

```
namespace{
    extern int count = -1;
};
```

cpp:

```
std::cout << count;
```

Comment: I just tired it but I am getting similar error saying: unresolved external symbol "int `anonymous namepsace::count`

Answer (score -2):

You should define an extern int in a header and a int into one file, but this file should be without any reference to the header

Comment: Including the declaring header in the defining .cpp file is not a problem, even with the `extern` decl.